# qt5 translations not working from different sources

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am making a python project using PyQt5. I have two files: `main_window.py`, where I configure the GUI for the window

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.package_name_label = QLabel(self.tr('Package for installation:'))
...
```

and the program itself (`update_viewer.py`), which inherits from MainWindow from main_window.py.

```
class PackageViewer(MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle(self.tr('Install and update packages'))
...
```

I specify the translations in each of these files using `tr()`, then get the `.ts` file using `pylupdate5` and use Qt Linguist: I have all the lines to translate (from both `main_window.py` and `update_viewer.py`). Then I get the `.qm` file with `lrelease`, plug it in with `QTranslator()` in `main.py` (where the object from `update_viewer.py` is initialized).

As a result I have a half translated program - translations that are in `main_window.py` are not processed. As far as I understand, the problem may be related to contexts, but I couldn't figure it out.

P.S. My `.pro` file seems to be legit as I get every `tr()` in `.ts` file

```
SOURCES         +=  src/update_viewer.py \
                    src/main_window.py

TRANSLATIONS    +=  src/translations/update-viewer_ru.ts
```

Comment: It's explained in the [PyQt internationalisation documentation](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/i18n.html#differences-between-pyqt5-and-qt): `tr()` can only work on the context of the instance, not that of the (possibly inherited) class. Use `QApplication.translate(context, string)`.